# Multiple files upload without creating roadblock in php?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

What is the possibility to upload multiple files using Laravel Framework without making roadblock such as **"TIME OUT"** or **"INFINITE LOADING"**

Or Simply any process which can be used to upload multiple (e.g. a large number of images, say :50 ) files over server at a time without using loops.

As loops take pretty much time until we are not finished with all uploads.

Any Idea??

Comment: if you have to upload multiple files at once then you can achieve that by using AJAX.  loop through all the files and upload one file at a time.

Comment: I hate just referencing an external library, but https://www.plupload.com/ has done me well. The idea is each image upload is a seperate thread, then once all those are done, your main post thread is performed with the file data already on the server.

Comment: you can get it done on client side rather than upload it on the single request,

Comment: @Evinn isn't it possible at server side ?
RopAli
I can do it client side.
but there are some drawbacks.
such as what if the user uploading the file and the connection got out at mid upload?

Comment: @Scuzzy, That is a good link but i want it done by php.

Comment: Then you're going to have a hard time, 50 uploads is a lot of content to be posting at once. not just for the max upload size, but the execution length time.

Comment: @AnshumanGupta so you need to implement callback function in the client side which is when one of the upload is fail in the midway, and then you can terminate all the upload process, plus the process will be running parallel.

Comment: @Evinn, Thanks for your precious effort but sorry that is not what i am looking for.
I want it to be handled by server just as Server directly hold the files and keep this to itself.